# Turning two Integers into one float with , java

Tags: java

i want to turn two Integer x and y into one float like x,y
So basically 1 and 3 shud become 1,3

Not sure how to write this though:

```
float z = (float) x,y;
```

Comment: Are you using `,` as the decimal separator? And what is the effect of negative `x`, and / or `y`?

Comment: float never have "," in it.Use String manipulation to add comma support

Comment: Can you elaborate your question

Comment: @Balram if the locale is something like german, then 1,3 is ok as a formatter, and that is what timo means.

Comment: ohhh,,my bad,,Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. By using string concatenation, or mathematically.

String concatenation:

```
float z = new Float(x + "." + Math.abs(y));
```

Mathematically:

```
float z = x + (Math.abs(y) / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(y)) + 1)));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String xy = x+"."+y;
double d = Double.parseDouble(xy);
```

Comment: Same with Float Wrapper

Comment: Elegantly simple (if computationally expensive), but what happens if `x` and `y` are both negative?

Comment: If at least y negative, this returns : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-11.-23"

Comment: Which makes this a nice answer, plus one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
float z;
z = y;
while (z >= 1)
  z /= 10;
z += x;
```

This assumes that `y` is not negative.

If `y` may be negative you should try

```
z = Math.abs(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Float Wrapper

```
    int x=5;
    int y=3;
    Float f = new Float(x+"."+Math.abs(y));
```

This will give you a float value

```
    f.floatValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have an integral part (x), and a decimal part (y), and you want to aggregate that into a floating point number.

You can first make the decimal part by dividing itself by 10 until it gets lower than 1, and then add it to your integral part (properly converted to float)

```
float convert(int integralPart, int decimalPart) {
  float x = (float) integralPart;
  float y= (float)decimalPart;
  while(y>= 1) y= y/ 10.0F;

  return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fastest way:

```
float z = x + ((float)y)/10
```

y represents 3 .. so it should be divided by 10.